# Implicit OAuth 2.0 Grant Flow possible in Browser for VK.vom?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

I'm just trying out the API of VK.com and have a problem with how they handle Authentication.

To have access to a resource i need, my app must be a "standalone app", only allowing implicit OAuth grant flow, with redirect to vk.com/blank.html.

So from a serverside flow i'm unable to access the token attached to its URL at the end. Obviously this would work on (mobile) devices where i can access the lower level browser but i'm a bit lost to figure out how it would work from a standalone (or not, i have a backend) browser/JS app. Or if it is possible at all?
The only information i found so far was always using direct user credentials which i don't have/want. I Only need to access the final code attached to the url of the redirect to vk.com/blank.html so i can use it to fetch the access token via the backend (no client_secret in the browser).

Comment: when requesting "messages" permission the callback needs to be the vk.com/blank.html page, other than that a custom one can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serve Javascript on your callback URL that extracts the access_token from the fragment of the URL and POST's it to your server backend. There's sample code in the OpenID Connect spec that does this, see http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#FragmentNotes.

Here's another sample that uses an HTML form instead of an AJAX call:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function postOnLoad() {
        encoded = location.hash.substring(1).split('&');
        for (i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
          encoded[i].replace(/\+/g, " ");
          var n = encoded[i].indexOf("=");
          var input = document.createElement("input");
          input.type = "hidden";
          input.name = decodeURIComponent(encoded[i].substring(0, n));
          input.value = decodeURIComponent(encoded[i].substring(n+1));
          document.forms[0].appendChild(input);
        }
        document.forms[0].action = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'));
        document.forms[0].submit();
      }
    </script>
    <title>Submitting...</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="postOnLoad()">
    <p>Submitting...</p>
    <form method="post" action=""><p><input type="hidden" name="response_mode" value="fragment"></p></form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i could supply the callback page yes, unfortunately vk.com requires it to be https://vk.com/blank.html?code=somecode (where the code is attached when making the request there).

Comment: correction: this was only the case for one specific permission i was trying to request - without this permission (that i dont really need anyway), i can supply the callback url and its working fine - even for a serverside flow probably.